# How to selected a UITableViewCell in the datasource method

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am populating the `UITableViewCell` in it's `datasource` method and would like to set its selected state to `ON` if some condition occurs.

Problem is that the `UITableView` doesn't track the cell's state (because the cell hasn't been queued yet) and therefor this desired selection state is lost

For instance:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
   id someDataToPutInCell = [self.myData objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
   if ([someDataToPutInCell satisfies some condition]) {
       cell.data = someDataToPutInCell;
       // now I've tried 2 different methods to select the cell
       // first method - directly set the cell to selected - doesn't work because the tableview deselects it when enqueuing it back to the table view
       [cell setSelected:YES];
        // second method - doesn't work because the cell doesn't have an idx path yet
       NSIndexPath *idx = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
        [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:idx animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the problem -

In this example I tried to find the index path of the cell through the API `indexPathForCell` - which I was doing because the configuration portion of the cell was happening in a separate method (which didn't have access to the index path of the cell through the data source method ) I decided to use the index path directly instead of trying to search for it through the API and everything worked out.